# Why doesn't the boot entry show up? Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I added a patchguard disabled boot entry and the first time I restarted the computer there was a menu that let me choose between Windows 10 and Patchguard disabled. Now I'm stuck on patchguard disabled and at boot the menu to choose doesn't show up. Any solutions to this?

My msconfig boot section:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the PatchGuard documentation does [say](https://github.com/hfiref0x/UPGDSED):

> Using this program might render your computer into an unbootable state.

I suggest uninstalling PatchGuard as described in the documentation:

> In elevated command prompt type bcdedit /delete < patch guard disable
>   entry id >
>
> Navigate to Windows\System32 folder and delete ntkrnlmp.exe,
>   osloader.exe (BIOS boot) or osloader.efi (EFI boot)

If you cannot boot into Windows, you will be able to follow the above
instructions only after you manage to boot the computer.

If you have a Windows 10 boot CD or USB, do
[Repair Startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).
If you don’t have an installation disc, you’ll have to use another PC to
[download a copy of Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/).
You can then [create a DVD or USB install disc](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9585/how-to-setup-a-usb-flash-drive-to-install-windows-7/) to boot the computer.

Tools that could help :

- [Paragon Rescue Kit 14 Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/)
- [Easy Recovery Essentials](https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/?utm_source=neosmart&utm_medium=wiki&utm_campaign=Windows%2010%20Reinstall)
- [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Comment: My computer can boot up but it defaults to Patchguard disabled. How do I switch back to the default windows? And I didn't install from Github but from a private forum that is for cheating in CS:GO. It requires to disable Patchguard in order to not get detected.

Comment: Use bcdedit as described in [Changing the Default Boot Entry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/changing-the-default-boot-entry).